# How do I resolve SSH connections failing?

Tags: mysql, macos, ssh, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySqlWorkbench on a Mac and connecting to several remote servers using SSH.

2 of them are local - one in my local VM and one on the server across the room. The third is elsewhere on the world wide wobble.

I can happily open workbench and connect to my 2 local servers immediately.

I can open workbench and do nothing for hours and then connect to them and all still works.

I can open workbench and connect immediately to the remote server. All is good.

But, if I try to connect after any sort of delay (say an hour or so) to the real remote server, I get an error.

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
Tunnel error: Remote connection to 127.0.0.1:3306 failed: IOError('open SSH channel timeout',)

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

At this point, I close the app, reopen it, make the connection and all is good.

But it is VERY frustrating having to wait 30 seconds or so to realise I am not going to get a connection, then having to close the app and then reopen it.

Sometimes the app crashes, but not often enough.

Any advice on what I can do to help identify the issue and eliminate it?

Regards,

Richard.

Comment: Not a solution for the timeout but for a more convenient reconnect use Menu -> Query -> Reconnect to server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the scenario correctly, then you've got problems with the connection dying if it's idle for some time. Try setting the keepalive option to keep generating some packets every couple of seconds. This should prevent your connection from dying.

If you're setting up the connection yourself, add `-o TCPKeepAlive=yes` to the commandline. If it's some application starting the connection for you, then setting:

```
Host *
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

in your `~/.ssh/config` should do the trick.